# Cloudera Manager software upgrade to latest version

Tags: ssl, kerberos, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

Do we need to disable Kerberos and TLS before upgrading cloudera manager and cdh services.

I am planing to upgrade cloudera manager 5.9 to 5.11.2 but cloudera hadoop cluster is kerberos enabled and TLS level 3 enabled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded CDH few days back to latest version. I disabled security and enabled after upgradation. We can also do it without disabling the security but might face issues.

Answer (score 0):

No, enabled security settings shouldn't make any difference to an upgrade.

If you look at [Upgrading from CDH 5.4.0 or Higher to the Latest Release](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-11-x/topics/cdh_ig_upgrade_to_latest.html#topic_8_2_8) nothing is mentioned about Kerberos or TLS.

Comment: Yeah, cloudera didn't mention about disabling security.

Comment: Cloudera docs _do_ mention that you **cannot disable** Kerberos once it's enabled. Or rather, it's you and the multiple configuration files without support. Good luck.